# Get whether a field is NULL or not

Tags: python, django

I have the following query:

```
territories = Territory.objects.values_list(
              'territory_id', 'territory__name', 'hd_retail_price__isnull'
             ).order_by('territory__name').distinct()
```

However, django raises an error that `hd_retail_price__isnull` is not a field (which it is not). Is there a way to get a boolean on whether the field is null or not? Otherwise my `distinct` won't work.

I want to have:

```
SELECT territory_id, territory_name, ISNULL(hd_retail_price) FROM territory
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `.extra`:

```
territories = Territory.objects.extra(
    select={'has_hd': "ISNULL(hd_retail_price)"}
  ).values_list(
    'territory_id', 'territory__name', 'has_hd'
  ).order_by('territory__name').distinct()
```